# YUM Update Failed - Error in POSTIN scriptlet in rpm package

Tags: linux, redhat, python, yum

Running "yum update" and it gets to installing and then breaks. Not sure what the problem is. Google shows nothing.

```
Error in POSTIN scriptlet in rpm package gtk2-2.18.9-10.el6.x86_64
error: error creating temporary file /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.NB84HC: Invalid argument
error: Couldn't create temporary file for %post(gtk2-2.18.9-10.el6.x86_64): Invalid argument
  Updating   : e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-12.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                   44/378
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmtrans.py", line 387, in callback
    self._instCloseFile(  bytes, total, h )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmtrans.py", line 463, in _instCloseFile
    self.base.history.trans_data_pid_end(pid, state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/history.py", line 858, in trans_data_pid_end
    """, ('TRUE', self._tid, pid, state))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/sqlutils.py", line 168, in executeSQLQmark
    return cursor.execute(query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
error: python callback <bound method RPMTransaction.callback of <yum.rpmtrans.RPMTransaction instance at 0x45c2290>> failed, aborting!
```

With a check all:

```
yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, security
MySQL-client-5.5.27-1.cp.1132.x86_64 is obsoleted by MySQL-client-5.5.27-1.cp.1132.x86_64
MySQL-server-5.5.27-1.cp.1132.x86_64 is obsoleted by MySQL-server-5.5.27-1.cp.1132.x86_64
abrt-libs-2.0.8-6.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with abrt-libs-2.0.4-14.el6.centos.x86_64
audit-libs-2.2-2.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with audit-libs-2.1.3-3.el6.x86_64
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(bandmin.conf)
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(bmversion.pl)
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(services.conf)
32:bind-libs-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with 32:bind-libs-9.7.3-8.P3.el6_2.2.x86_64
cagefs-safebin-3.6-6.el6.cloudlinux.x86_64 is a duplicate with cagefs-safebin-3.5-1.el6.cloudlinux.x86_64
chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with chkconfig-1.3.49.3-1.el6_2.x86_64
cloudlinux-release-6-6.3.0.x86_64 is a duplicate with cloudlinux-release-6-6.2.2.x86_64
coreutils-8.4-19.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with coreutils-8.4-16.el6.x86_64
coreutils-libs-8.4-19.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with coreutils-libs-8.4-16.el6.x86_64
1:cups-libs-1.4.2-48.el6_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-44.el6_2.3.x86_64
1:dbus-libs-1.2.24-7.el6_3.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:dbus-libs-1.2.24-5.el6_1.x86_64
12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-31.P1.el6_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhcp-common-4.1.1-25.P1.el6_2.1.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-12.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-11.el6.x86_64
exim-4.80-0.x86_64 has missing requires of perl(SafeFile)
expat-2.0.1-11.el6_2.x86_64 is a duplicate with expat-2.0.1-9.1.el6.x86_64
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gawk-3.1.7-9.el6.x86_64
glib2-2.22.5-7.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with glib2-2.22.5-6.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64
gtk2-2.18.9-10.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with gtk2-2.18.9-6.el6.centos.x86_64
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.noarch is obsoleted by kernel-firmware-2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.noarch
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.noarch is obsoleted by kernel-firmware-2.6.32-379.5.1.lve1.1.9.6.1.el6.noarch
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-379.5.1.lve1.1.9.6.1.el6.noarch is a duplicate with kernel-firmware-2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.noarch
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-379.5.1.lve1.1.9.6.1.el6.noarch is obsoleted by kernel-firmware-2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.noarch
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-379.5.1.lve1.1.9.6.1.el6.noarch is obsoleted by kernel-firmware-2.6.32-379.5.1.lve1.1.9.6.1.el6.noarch
kernel-headers-2.6.32-379.5.1.lve1.1.9.6.1.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with kernel-headers-2.6.32-320.4.1.lve1.1.4.el6.x86_64
keyutils-libs-1.4-4.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with keyutils-libs-1.4-3.el6.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.9-33.el6_3.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with krb5-libs-1.9-22.el6_2.1.x86_64
libblkid-2.17.2-12.7.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libblkid-2.17.2-12.4.el6.x86_64
libcom_err-1.41.12-12.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcom_err-1.41.12-11.el6.x86_64
libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libselinux-2.0.94-5.2.el6.x86_64
libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
libtiff-3.9.4-6.el6_3.x86_64 is a duplicate with libtiff-3.9.4-5.el6_2.x86_64
libudev-147-2.42.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libudev-147-2.40.el6.x86_64
libuuid-2.17.2-12.7.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libuuid-2.17.2-12.4.el6.x86_64
libxml2-2.7.6-8.el6_3.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with libxml2-2.7.6-4.el6_2.4.x86_64
nspr-4.9.1-2.el6_3.x86_64 is a duplicate with nspr-4.8.9-3.el6_2.x86_64
nss-util-3.13.5-1.el6_3.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-util-3.13.1-3.el6_2.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.5.x86_64
python-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with python-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64
python-libs-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with python-libs-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64
readline-6.0-4.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with readline-6.0-3.el6.x86_64
sed-4.2.1-10.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64
tzdata-2012c-3.el6.noarch is a duplicate with tzdata-2012c-1.el6.noarch
xmlrpc-c-1.16.24-1209.1840.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with xmlrpc-c-1.16.24-1200.1840.el6_1.4.x86_64
xmlrpc-c-client-1.16.24-1209.1840.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with xmlrpc-c-client-1.16.24-1200.1840.el6_1.4.x86_64
Error: check all
```

Tried:

```
#rm /var/lib/rpm/__db*
#rpm --rebuilddb
#yum clean all
```

Tried also running

```
yum-complete-transaction
```

still won't finish the update.

```
ls -ld /var/tmp/
drwxrwxrwt. 20 root root 12288 Oct  3 18:44 /var/tmp/

 df -h /var/tmp/
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/tmp                  3.9G  1.2G  2.6G  32% /var/tmp
```

Latest errors:

```
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.i686 != libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.i686 != glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64
```

EDITED:

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * cloudlinux-x86_64-server-6: cl.banahosting.com
repo id                                                                          repo name                                                                         status
cloudlinux-x86_64-server-6                                                       CloudLinux Server 6 x86_64                                                        10,948+725
repolist: 10,948

[~]# package-cleanup --dupes
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin
xmlrpc-c-client-1.16.24-1209.1840.el6.x86_64
xmlrpc-c-client-1.16.24-1200.1840.el6_1.4.x86_64
bind-libs-9.7.3-8.P3.el6_2.2.x86_64
bind-libs-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.3.x86_64
libblkid-2.17.2-12.4.el6.x86_64
libblkid-2.17.2-12.7.el6.x86_64
libtiff-3.9.4-5.el6_2.x86_64
libtiff-3.9.4-6.el6_3.x86_64
audit-libs-2.1.3-3.el6.x86_64
audit-libs-2.2-2.el6.x86_64
libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64
sed-4.2.1-10.el6.x86_64
sed-4.2.1-7.el6.x86_64
python-libs-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64
python-libs-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64
coreutils-libs-8.4-16.el6.x86_64
coreutils-libs-8.4-19.el6.x86_64
libudev-147-2.40.el6.x86_64
libudev-147-2.42.el6.x86_64
chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.el6.x86_64
chkconfig-1.3.49.3-1.el6_2.x86_64
keyutils-libs-1.4-4.el6.x86_64
keyutils-libs-1.4-3.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64
tzdata-2012c-3.el6.noarch
tzdata-2012c-1.el6.noarch
coreutils-8.4-19.el6.x86_64
coreutils-8.4-16.el6.x86_64
dbus-libs-1.2.24-7.el6_3.x86_64
dbus-libs-1.2.24-5.el6_1.x86_64
libxml2-2.7.6-4.el6_2.4.x86_64
libxml2-2.7.6-8.el6_3.3.x86_64
abrt-libs-2.0.8-6.el6.x86_64
abrt-libs-2.0.4-14.el6.centos.x86_64
expat-2.0.1-9.1.el6.x86_64
expat-2.0.1-11.el6_2.x86_64
python-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64
python-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64
gtk2-2.18.9-6.el6.centos.x86_64
gtk2-2.18.9-10.el6.x86_64
libcom_err-1.41.12-12.el6.x86_64
libcom_err-1.41.12-11.el6.x86_64
gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.x86_64
gawk-3.1.7-9.el6.x86_64
readline-6.0-4.el6.x86_64
readline-6.0-3.el6.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64
libselinux-2.0.94-5.2.el6.x86_64
libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6.x86_64
cups-libs-1.4.2-48.el6_3.1.x86_64
cups-libs-1.4.2-44.el6_2.3.x86_64
nspr-4.9.1-2.el6_3.x86_64
nspr-4.8.9-3.el6_2.x86_64
cagefs-safebin-3.5-1.el6.cloudlinux.x86_64
cagefs-safebin-3.6-6.el6.cloudlinux.x86_64
libuuid-2.17.2-12.4.el6.x86_64
libuuid-2.17.2-12.7.el6.x86_64
xmlrpc-c-1.16.24-1209.1840.el6.x86_64
xmlrpc-c-1.16.24-1200.1840.el6_1.4.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.5.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.x86_64
dhcp-common-4.1.1-25.P1.el6_2.1.x86_64
dhcp-common-4.1.1-31.P1.el6_3.1.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.9-33.el6_3.3.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.9-22.el6_2.1.x86_64
nss-util-3.13.5-1.el6_3.x86_64
nss-util-3.13.1-3.el6_2.x86_64
cloudlinux-release-6-6.2.2.x86_64
cloudlinux-release-6-6.3.0.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-11.el6.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-12.el6.x86_64
glib2-2.22.5-6.el6.x86_64
glib2-2.22.5-7.el6.x86_64
```

UPDATE 2

I removed all the dupes and then did update and got this:

```
Updating   : sudo-1.7.4p5-13.el6_3.x86_64                                                                                                                           79/361
Error in POSTIN scriptlet in rpm package sudo-1.7.4p5-13.el6_3.x86_64
warning: /etc/sudoers created as /etc/sudoers.rpmnew
error: error creating temporary file /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.hjTOqJ: Invalid argument
error: Couldn't create temporary file for %post(sudo-1.7.4p5-13.el6_3.x86_64): Invalid argument
  Updating   : pcre-7.8-6.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                  80/361
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmtrans.py", line 399, in callback
    self._instCloseFile(  bytes, total, h )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmtrans.py", line 475, in _instCloseFile
    self.base.history.trans_data_pid_end(pid, state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/history.py", line 858, in trans_data_pid_end
    """, ('TRUE', self._tid, pid, state))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/sqlutils.py", line 168, in executeSQLQmark
    return cursor.execute(query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
error: python callback <bound method RPMTransaction.callback of <yum.rpmtrans.RPMTransaction instance at 0x5c7cfc8>> failed, aborting!
```

-

```
[~]# lsattr /var/tmp/
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_5b07945563e03aec1c44917886fd99a6
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_6edfafda1a191f6986bd020ed945eea0
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_1b837feecdd4c9e6aa6ecd81d41fda75
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_70bec5f392b4f5f75ac444f5c82db2dc
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_24cd226ba0a370a6d3838a37745b2e15
-------------e- /var/tmp/nginx_proxy
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_19fb1dd060e42c9de8786ef34d7fcf6e
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_b4ac777076c5122a6e27d776de0a2fcb
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_5077441775ef8d07a2185e8fd48a4aa8
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_4e71d930fe8250e222ae4d1dc39646ff
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_eb6eb29b38b55b85303c3137611f0a2faa15c21d
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_81e7e8d93b395f2c8d7e3fe12cc59e56
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_05c7f305bdbf9a4c7af251d33ac59766
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_0ad9369063a37b6b399688a835d69ed2
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_c780deda617678faeea8f8a34395ac27
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_9773332e3c99ee18dca0b05e8f02a41e
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_1d9b02b068ea81a3975599ddc12bcfb1
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_1ffeff444123e924834dc5e80d07571e
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_aa56725471c84d9a06745c56dc499db7
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_51e19964d7e1a164c63f4c72fa43475c33debbc0
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_a83c7a05bb189a465b8813ff9e566aa8f9124079
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_2f506ba5b77c61107871e8cf80393cdb
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_7bfe1578605b259ec5e4fd2200df4cd0
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_f6e47011789d8d48d56dd78a398d98d5719414a7
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_b7c43a90a8b8d8f02b0fffca77796ce5
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_6c3e7103453ad4daba815bd96a903785
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_86f32a22507d8410b3f0fc7d71a135d5
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_aaf72d3e8cfb2f27ffdff61323f97e7553855a05
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_5de4488e2ee03ac0f99ab9494573ccb1
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_716d97bba4abdb38704a9e4212f6fddc
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_534908a9510a32eda13a5dc95ac022cc
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_626a58203d93427c79621ea4fec0906d
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_827ca92d10d3797f2c187c41764a7036
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_6282962d77f7bead20e785fbdb9a3d8f
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_b012c8a729fc54a296a700ed92930a0e
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_631e5ba769773da056108d3fbd143963
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_30bb7f1333ba5f96a229c91a3385d8b5
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_93e085706b29c3e4e3593bfe39b1079e
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_abd78bd6c285d681c90de8c617747ab3
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_e144544ed925569018e6607b05f43f253f75e2aa
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_5d3d036c772847a4508d3e100b173d84
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_f35243d1f40bd8d9ce08940fafc00d93
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_761c3ffa811b959638ed0b266741eaa4
-------------e- /var/tmp/mm.sem.sNdxjf
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_006d45dbd807291f7bffbd1db3707ed6
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_2d0162aac9f87c1978ac644923a5e2fe
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_22c534418c380b72d105935b59713dd1
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_94f72ef408567a15f6287c518e93898e
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_6fe03c83bb87489f3921db1c974dfc0e
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_48bbfa2a2a8793a62c7fd6a389a2763e
-------------e- /var/tmp/mm.sem.ERERMV
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_20aba82c03a69b2dc6af66c499c38ee67e27368f
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_f94fe0589a79c934815ef359bcb0a16c7080d937
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_460390801eb004593b4dee83779f414e
-------------e- /var/tmp/spamd-52811-init
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_6427fdb235d59b0b2fbd105bf23d2e87
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_4ce12d8350d7c0361dc1bf15d552a2d8
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_039fec2a643340f118b6355e4c836ae8
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_fa46fa80b26e6cf3d9c7de942d5dbcff
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_664858e614367812148716536e22d030
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_4c8d4c44fbd828dc17415ce6aa213115
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_d231a6c0e5dd4d7bacbf9de3d8bb298f
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_a82f8a088a8e37d375f6a9fede4a54d2
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_604697227ae5359e5783dc9407845338
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_5b4e623536640abe671b40563d03817d
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_2aba0aff64f3c18f22e0b79d591259e2
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_bfd52a2d2d80880f8e26ad460739a0494f0d1e9e
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_ba9f3e3a7c7111930d6b801aaa833b46
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_5cc8c5b620015a465359359a0805fbdd
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_84945c41d604b4653a1bf45d83a1917c
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_5f52569b27430780c07d25cfb8177e5c1ef647f0
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_45896aef9e77f16be1b3e94b3edb2599
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_5a67d0ef8f826a2f103b429c8464bdd5f75d6218
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_1fce98bb32e5b34c79fd5a313de32980
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_f7ea772ff3fbb1eb2ad8712dd2c49ed8
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_a9dc16bc5c1eb2768bb2600f0d102fde
-------------e- /var/tmp/mm.sem.3zwRTu
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_e2cad140703338a4b8c9254ec6b0a1a2
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_e7c8e85daf9c5424aecb83e066decf31
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_800f878fa944370f42e76057e7c033e19520bd41
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_4fdae64eb18599521ace18679795568b
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_958fb886b97de2e767b059376c4724b5
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_3c832a31f17744a8bb3c59dde02e561aefbc2e48
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_6d9d7bf04f34e0d82b101f882196a905
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_7231c75ae4fad2ca5fbcb6de430a7b13
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_2eadffa2285def9673ce784395d272d8
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_2ff353b664d8028df967f807ac18593a
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_4138a267f1f5e3ad93c1d64547c63134ae7c0db3
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_64cd9fa0d6af8e8041aafffbe3db986a
-------------e- /var/tmp/tmpg3ycIG
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_b633ac8283d6de8e39d81160d63fc8cd
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_2cee03cf5eafd3ef55d8efa1b0390436
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_608066c609e28621f2a29ac04a3a6441
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_46dfb35cf8266699ba9304e5d8c6869d
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_fb202a0ed54cee8832c5f6e0ca7fc1b3
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_8fe3c5fd8cdda02855e5f9b5a1ea85a4
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_941376d5cb51e0ba73f9a27ee259c159
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_4fa17b1eac1d18341d20d0d8d4991ceb
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_de647c956ca6a1b75744ad194aceaa82
-------------e- /var/tmp/mm.sem.Ugu7Be
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_656e8a50759d5b36b963e7eb85e0bb0d
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_983f77b607bbffa1748d6c49557381e9
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_632860d092e5e374da522ed2f88e83ce
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_030f900b81cc2a4ad095d53ef3ee0791
-------------e- /var/tmp/yum.log
-------------e- /var/tmp/cache_810174993c6a2c0efe2edbe4c39a4a81
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_29e2c781643434e81d189fc41f47fd34
-------------e- /var/tmp/tmpE12ahd
-------------e- /var/tmp/sess_935da512fb077e04610266748b3b77f3
```

-

```
cat /etc/fstab
/tmp as: loop,rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check to make sure you have free space? Run a `df -h` to see.

Also check the permissions on the required temporary directories. Run `ls -ld /var/tmp/`.

Update:

I would just download the [offending package](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.3/x86_64/Packages/e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-12.el6.x86_64.html) directly, OR see if you can install `yum-utils` (either via `yum` *OR* [direct download](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/yum-utils-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch.rpm) and `rpm -ivh yum-utils*`).

From there, try:

```
package-cleanup --dupes
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

Then run your `yum update` again.

Comment: added above to show better.

Comment: @TiffanyWalker See my edit above.

Comment: I ran --cleandupes and it wants to remove 166 packages/395MB worth. sound about right?

Comment: @TiffanyWalker Maybe? What happened leading up to this? Were there any repository changes? Did yum work properly before? Can you run `yum repolist`?

Comment: not ran an update in 3-4 months. posted contents up in post.

Comment: Cleaned out the dupes, worked, then crashed on me again. same way and does not look like a lack of disk space :(

Comment: @TiffanyWalker The same error? Try repeating, but also running an `rpm --rebuilddb` somewhere in there.

Comment: Yea, same error. Posted above. Should I do a rebuild after I remove dupes?

Comment: Yeah you have another issue. It could be permissions, filesystem, immutable files... But this is beyond the scope of where I can help you. One last thing. Try running `lsattr /var/tmp/` and post the output.

Comment: Updated. Maybe it's how /tmp is mounted?

Comment: @TiffanyWalker Yes, it's the fact that your /tmp is mounted `noexec`. Try this: `mount -o remount,rw /tmp` and re-run your yum updates.